# What is the opposite of middleware in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, transformer-model

Middleware in Laravel can be used to add app wide logic (or specific to specific routes or group of routes) *before* any application/business logic is applied. I want to do the same, but *after* all the application/business logic is done. What I love about middleware is that it centralizes the place where said logic is applied. Is there a way to do that at the end of the request/response lifecycle?

One option is using [transformers](https://fractal.thephpleague.com/transformers/), but I don't find it as clean as middleware for some reason (maybe because it's done by a third party?)

sample use case: I want to have a group of endpoints always return values in an alternate currency rather than USD only when such requests are made from a certain type of shoppers from a certain geographical area (which I already know). So I will need to perform business logic, and then right before I send the json response back, I want to "hijack" said response and replace all USD values with another currency of my choosing.

Ideas? (I'm using Laravel 5.5)

Comment: How about `Resources`?

Comment: @TharakaDilshan what's that? can you provide a reference please?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-resources

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55428175/how-does-laravel-know-whether-a-middleware-should-be-run-after-the-request-handl

Answer (score 6):

You can do it in.... the middleware right after the call for the closure

```php
/**
 * @param Request $request
 * @param \Closure $next
 * @return Response
 */
public function handle(Request $request, \Closure $next)
{
    //middleware logic
    $response = $next($request); //dont return it
    //post application/business logic here
    return $response;
}
```

**Edit** from @ceejayoz comment:

You can use `terminate()` method in your middleware class to run code **After** that  the response has been sent to the client with the condition that your web server is using FastCGI.

```php
public function handle(Request $request, \Closure $next)
{
    //middleware logic
    return $next($request); //dont return it
}

public function terminate($request, $response)
{
    //post application/business logic here
    //no need for return instruction
}
```

**Edit 2**
For transformation of the json output, the best solution would be to use the `ResourceCollection`.

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Resources;

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\ResourceCollection;

class Product extends ResourceCollection
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource collection into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        $multiplier = $isUs?1.2:1;
        return [
            'price' = $this->price * $multiplier,
        ];
    }
}
```

In your controller use this class as the response for the controller

```php
public function show($productId)
{
    return new \App\Http\Resources\Product(Product::find($productId));
}
```

Comment: Documented at https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/middleware under "Before & After Middleware". There's also terminable middleware for *after* a response has been sent.

Comment: @ceejayoz thanks for the info, didn't notice the `terminate()` method before

Comment: @ceejayoz the condition of `FastCGI` is what made me dismiss it the first time i saw it. Didn't want to risk it knowing i can't change production server.